# Sorting tasks by due date?

Tags: tasks

We're using SharePoint's Microsoft Project-like functionality for a small project. I've entered the list of tasks into the system, and it's producing a nice little Gant chart.

The problem is my tasks are listed in the order I entered them in. I'd like to sort them by due date. When I click on the due date column and select Sort Ascending, nothing happens. (My data does not sort)

Is there any work around or other way to sort by date? I'd hate to have to re-enter all my tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to change the view of the list to sort it by?

1. Go to the tasks list.
2. On the ribbon, go to the List tab, then Modify View
3. Go down to Sort and try to Sort by Due Date
4. Click OK

Comment: This is the answer. The default sorting is by ID, which is basically by created time, for the list which is why you see them in that order.

Comment: You're right, it worked...I wonder why there's an Excel like filter on the column headings that doesn't even work, though. Bug?